# Is there a way to get a list of user relationships?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have not found other references in the Graph API other than the present [relationship_status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user). I am after getting the history of person's relationships. Is that possible (people with whom person had "in relationship" status)?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: This should be answer then.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

The API does not provide a "history" for this.

Comment: It does not seem that the API provides the current relationship either? It tells the status "in relationship", but doesn't give the ID of the person.

Comment: The field `significant_other` provided that info in API 1.0; and while it is still listed in the docs for v2.1, I am not sure what it provides now – might be that with the recent changes and app-scoped user ids and all that it will only give that info if the person the user is in a relationship with also uses the app …

Comment: Oh, just learned about the introduction of the app-scoped user ids. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids